# Could not cast value of type 'CALayer' (0x1a89c32a8) to 'CAGradientLayer'

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, swift3

Since migrating my project to Swift 3 I am getting a runtime crash with the following error in the console.

```
Could not cast value of type 'CALayer' (0x1a89c32a8) to 'CAGradientLayer'
```

I have a ViewController where I change the class of the view to my custom gradient class.

The problem is the following line;

```
let layer = self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
```

However I do not understand why because self.layer is type `CALayer` and `CAGradientLayer` is a subclass of `CALayer` so my understanding is casting the type types should be ok.. as it was in swift 2.2.

Can anyone help me out where I am going wrong so I can understand the issue a little more ?

Here's my full gradient class

```
@IBDesignable public class JGradientView: UIView {

@IBInspectable public var topColor: UIColor? {
    didSet {
        configureGradientView()
    }
}
@IBInspectable public var bottomColor: UIColor? {
    didSet {
        configureGradientView()
    }
}
@IBInspectable var startX: CGFloat = 0.0 {
    didSet{
        configureGradientView()
    }
}
@IBInspectable var startY: CGFloat = 1.0 {
    didSet{
        configureGradientView()
    }
}
@IBInspectable var endX: CGFloat = 0.0 {
    didSet{
        configureGradientView()
    }
}
@IBInspectable var endY: CGFloat = 0.0 {
    didSet{
        configureGradientView()
    }
}

public class func layeredClass() -> AnyClass {
    return CAGradientLayer.self
}

public required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    configureGradientView()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    configureGradientView()
}

public override func tintColorDidChange() {
    super.tintColorDidChange()
    configureGradientView()
}

func configureGradientView() {

    let color1 = topColor ?? self.tintColor as UIColor
    let color2 = bottomColor ?? UIColor.black as UIColor
    let colors: Array <AnyObject> = [ color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor ]
    let layer = self.layer as! CAGradientLayer

    layer.colors = colors
    layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY)
    layer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: endX, y: endY)
}
}
```

Comment: For now replace your line with `let layer = self.layer as? CAGradientLayer` to get rid of the error, and underneath add a `?` to the three lines after `layer`. Next add `print(self.layer)`, this will print out the class of the layer, as it may be a type of layer that cannot be cast to a gradient layer.

Comment: You can always upcast, not necessarily downcast. – But the real error is that `layeredClass` should be  `layerClass` (and you have to add `override`).

Comment: Alright thanks guys, sorry sometimes you don't find the answer when you're asking the wrong question. But your answers worked !